# How to retrieve value from queryset in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to retrieve different `.values()` from query sets but am having an issue with it returning the proper values. How to write my `model` so that I can retrieve attributes using the `.values()` method?

I have tried to change the model's `__str__` method to return a dictionary but that does not work or I am doing it wrong.

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    bb_bonus_qualify = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=38.00)
    service_breakpoint = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=1700.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s, %s: %s' % (
            'bb_bonus', self.bb_bonus_qualify, 'service_breakpoint', self.service_breakpoint)
```

I would like to say `Settings.objects.last().values('bb_bonus')` and be returned the value which is `self.bb_bonus_qualify`. The common error I seem to get is: `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: You should use a different order, so `Settings.objects.values_list('bb_bonus_qualify', flat=True).last()`, but probably I do not understand it properly.

Comment: That worked. I found it all in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your `.last()` will retrieve the *last* `Settings` object. You thus will call `.values('bb_bonus')` on the `Settings` object. Since a model has no `.values(..)` method, it will thus not return anything.

You can however retrieve the value of a certain column from a queryset, with:

```
Settings.objects.values_list('bb_bonus_qualify', flat=True).last()
```

We here thus use [**`.values_list(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), this accepts the names of the columns as parameters. It will then usually return a `QuerySet` of lists with these values. But if you specify *one* column; then, as the documentation says:

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the `flat` parameter. If **`True`, this will mean the returned results are single values**, rather than one-tuples.

So that means we create a `QuerySet` of singular values, and we then will retrieve the last entry of that queryset. Note that we do *not* fetch all the elements from the queryset, the `.last()` is "injected" in the query we perform on the database, so the result is the scalar value of that column for the last record.

The `.values_list(..)` thus needs to be performed *before* the `.last()`, since otherwise you are talking to a `Settings` object, not to a `QuerySet`.

Comment: @DavidAlford: are you sure?  I've tested this with a `QuerySet` with one element, and it looked ok.

Comment: @DavidAlford: the `__str__` method normally does not change anything, but I can not reproduce your problem locally anyway.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `__str__` has nothing to do with `.values()` - the problem here is that you need to specify the values *before* getting a specific item, rather than the other way round:

```
Settings.objects.values('bb_bonus').last()
```